# How to make Fiddler generate certificate with wrong CN

Tags: security, fiddler

I need it for security testing. **My purpose is to check, how the application would behave, if the adversary presents a certificate with a wrong Common Name (CN)** and/or SubjectAltName, but signed by a correct CA.

I believe that the application in test uses HostnameVerifier incorrectly and need to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an official answer from Telerik (Eric Lawrence):

Click *Rules > Customize Rules*. Scroll to *OnBeforeRequest*.

Inside that function, add the following:

```
   if (oSession.HTTPMethodIs("CONNECT") && 
       oSession.HostnameIs("siteIcareabout.com"))
   {
         oSession["X-OverrideCertCN"] = "badhostname.net";
   }
```

Save the file and restart the browser if it had previously established any connections to https://siteIcareabout.com.

==========================
I checked it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla Fiddler lacks a mechanism to do this, so you would need to use an external tool or plugin. Some examples are [cataloged here](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/faq---certificates-in-fiddler).

Of course, any certificate you generate will be signed by the Fiddler root cert, so the platform you're running the application from will need to trust that certificate